# Is the birthday of Fuuka Akitsuki known?

Tags: fuuka

In the latest episodes, Yuu regrets not knowing the birthday of Fuuka (ch37 pg 16). Digging [wikia](http://fuukaakitsuki.wikia.com/wiki/Fuuka_Akitsuki), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Suzuka_characters#F.C5.ABka_Akitsuki), [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/character/100811/Fuuka_Akitsuki), or just straight googling, nothing came up on her birthday.

Since she made cameos in two prequel series already, is her birthday known?

If her birthday is not know, can it be at least narrowed down to a season or month from the source material?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Fuuka is born on the same day as Yuu. If you ask about Akitsuki Fuuka.

Comment: Where did you find that? Can you provide a source?

Comment: [Here](http://fuukaakitsuki.wikia.com/wiki/Fuuka_Akitsuki) you can find a source for his statement. Just look in the section 'Trivia'.